# How to identify if given number is there in a given array range?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have an array which stores numbers. The count of numbers varies time to time. There is another variable which a holds number, and I need to find out in which range `$num` falls. In the above case `$num` falls under 64. (Bigger than 32 and less than 64)

```
$ar = array(0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224);

$num = 44;
```

How do I crack this?

Comment: First sort the array then find index of your number then one below and one above that are your answers

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ, the array contains only the ranges, not the used number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ar = array(0, 32, 64, 96, 128, 160, 192, 224);

$num = 44;

$range = min(array_filter($ar, function($i) use($num) {
    return $i > $num;
}));

var_dump($range);
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/KV6MWD

Comment: I like this Zmayte. If only there was a nice way to terminate `array_filter()` only.

Comment: With a sorted array, you can also do this in O(log n) time, instead of the O(n) time that a linear scan would take.  You simply do a binary search until the left and right choices are lower and higher than your number.

Comment: @SubSevn: with sorted array - yes

Comment: @SubSevn That would be after you profiled your application and determined this particular part of code to be the bottleneck, right? ;)

Comment: Nice solution, add an example also with for the number before, like $range = max(array_filter($ar, function($i) use($num) {
    return $i < $num;
}));

Comment: @Sam: actually in the *original* revision of the question OP asked about upper boundary. After question was edited - this requirement was lost. But anyway - let it be a homework for OP (though you've provided it already :-)